# does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

Tags: python, datetime, format, match

Can't see the issue with not matching the format.

```
chDate = []
for value in sheet.iter_cols(min_row=2,min_col=6,max_col=6, values_only=True):
    chDate.append(str(value))


chDate = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for d in chDate]
```

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCRtA.jpg)

Comment: Please add exemplary content of `chDate` - see [mre]. It seems to contain lists of values; however strptime expects scalar values.

Comment: chDate is the data added into from a excel column, in this case dates.

Comment: if `chDate` is a list of timestamp strings, you need to parse these individually; you can use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) for your format.

Comment: Nvm I change chDate.append(str(value)) to chDate = list(value2)and now it works.